# Need to delete row from the table

Tags: sql

I had a table as example below. I need to delete a particular row that contains both subscriber_id=6 and queue_id=148. What is the Query to delete it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgZTR.png)

Comment: `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 12`?

Comment: Perhaps by learning the SQL [DELETE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) Statement? And [AND](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) for the [WHERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) clause.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is to be trivially found in the documentation, and it is highly unlikely that will be of anyone's use in the future.

Answer (score 1):

learn SQL delete statement here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

here is your answer

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE subscriber_id=6 and queue_id=148
```